# MySQL conditional referencing of foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a schema with nullable foreign key.
Basically, this is what I want to achieve:

Given:

table 1:

```
game:
  id
  observer_id
  starts_on
  ends_on
  type
```

table 2:

```
observer:
  id
  game_id DEFAULT NULL
  starts_on
  ends_on
  type
  FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `game`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Now, what I want to do - I want to duplicate as the initial values and update on cascade `starts_on`, `ends_on` and `type` fields in `observer` table if I have a reference to a `game`, however if `game_id` is null I want to have an independent values for above mentioned fields. Is something like this possible with `IF` in mysql or should I implement the logic in my model files?

Comment: I am not getting the requirement, what do you mean by "I want to duplicate as the initial values"? I am also not clear about the update requirement. And on Delete, what Independent value do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Consider to solve your issue while data retrieving (SELECT) instead of data manipulation (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).

```
select
    o.id,
    o.game_id,
    coalesce(g.starts_on, o.starts_on) as starts_on,
    coalesce(g.ends_on,   o.ends_on)   as ends_on,
    coalesce(g.type,      o.type)      as type
from observer o
left join game g on g.id = o.game_id
```

In this query if `o.game_id` is `NULL` the LEFT JOIN will find no matches in the `game` table and all its columns will also be `NULL`. Then `COALESCE()` will take care of choosing the value from the `game` table if present or from `observer` otherwise.

You can use that query in a VIEW (if you like), but i can't tell if it will perform well in any use case.

This way you can store your "independent" values without worrying if the `game id` is set or not, since they will only be used, if the `game_id` is not `NULL`.

Note that your problem might be solved in a more "clean" way changing the schema. With the columns `game.observer_id` and `observer.game_id` it looks like a *cyclic* relation, which can be considered as *"design smell"*. But without knowledge of your data logic I can't suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEYs` do a limited number of things.  Once you go beyond them, you should build your own transaction in your app code (or Stored Procedure or ...) to do the more complex things.

I feel that this is the safer route, since you know exactly what you need, and won't have to try to shoehorn FKs into doing it.